# Copy and unzip from S3 to HDFS

Tags: json, apache-spark, amazon-s3, zip, gzip

I have a few large zip files on S3. Each of these zip files contains several gz files, which contain data in JSON format. I need to (i) Copy the gz files to HDFS and (ii) Process the files preferably by Apache Spark/Impala/Hive. What is the easiest/best way of going about it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try distcp for copying files from s3 to HDFS

2) For processing, use "`org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext`"'s `read.json` for reading JSON data from HDFS and create dataframe.
Then do any operation on it.

Follow this link,
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes

Comment: How do I "unzip" the zip files on HDFS? Can I do it programmatically using Spark? How?